# Laravel: 404 error in routing to the same location

Tags: laravel

web.php

```php
  Route::get('/', 'TodosController@index');
  Route::resource('todos', 'TodosController');
```

navbar.blade.php

```php
    <a class="nav-link" href="todos/create">Create</a>
```

When I am in the home/index page and click **Create link** on the navbar it works.

However when I am already in the Create page and click on **Create link**, I get a 404 Error because the link is parsed like this:

`todolist.test/todos/todos/create`

How do I fix this so that the link remains to be
`todolist.test/todos/create`?

Comment: have you tried to use the URL helpers to generate absolute URLs instead of using relative ones that are based on your current directory/url segment?   https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/urls

Comment: Awesome! I went to YouTube and typed what you said, "URL helpers" and found this video; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QQl7VJKRoTg

It works now. Thank you.

Comment: nice, figured the doc link would be a good start but what gets you there :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should check out this documentation:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers

In this page especially check out this part:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am using Laravel 7 and I followed this:

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/controllers#resource-controllers

Comment: @NoOne yeah i just wanted to show you that Actions Handled By Resource Controller(the one in above picture)  which is the same for every versions.

Comment: Ok. Thanks a bunch.